# mac os in Virtualbox does bot recognize Iphone

Tags: iphone

My host computer is ubuntu, and i have installed a virtualbox with macOS 10.14.6
i works fine i can connect my andorid but i can't add my iPhone to my Virtualbox.

How can i connect a iphone to to my virtualbox.?
i't loses connection on the virtualbox

steps:

> Devices -> USB -> apple inc. iPhone - 
>   I can't connect the iphone.

i got this error code here:

```
Failed to create a proxy device for the USB (Error VERR_READ_ERROR)
```

It works on iPhone 6. It does not work on iPhone 7

Comment: Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

MacOS has changed the policy of USB in virtual machine passthrough.  And the iPhone 6 already does not have technical support from Apple, but it can still be connected to VirtualBox. 
Starting from the iPhone 7, Apple support blocks the ability to connect the device to  VirtualBox. I use [USB over ethernet](https://www.usb-over-ethernet.org/usb-in-virtual-machine/usb-in-virtualbox/) to connect and test apps on the iPhone. I hope this problem will be solved with a free option at the nearest time.

Comment: USB over ethernet software cannot be installed on Ubuntu 20

Comment: Version 20 was released only at the end of April. I am sure that at the moment few people use this version for stable operation and using all software. Everything worked on all previous versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed on Ubuntu 20. You need to add a repository from qt4.
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
; sudo apt-get update`.  and after `sudo dpkg -i eveusb.deb
; sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Next, i face error "Deamon unreachable".


Then, i found it works using sudo.


`sudo eveusb`


https://www.usb-over-ethernet.org/user-guides/commandline-options/


Thank Micahel. Now i can continue work on iOS using Ubuntu 20,